# How to make countdown timer like in browser games?

Tags: php

I would like to know how to make countdown timer in PHP. In browser games, for example; when you build up a building or do start a research, a countdown starts for that building etc.. and when you shut down computer or website and open it back from another computer or somewhere else you see that the countdown is still working. Could you briefly explain how it works or what should I search on google to have some idea about it?

Thank you!

Comment: @Dagon are you really funny?

Comment: @HddnTHA no but i do play a clown on TV

Comment: @Dagon uhm is there any countdown there like in some websites?

Comment: A countdown timer in php? You don't. You use javascript. Php fully executes before the user even sees the page because it runs on the server. You need client side scripting for this.

Comment: @mopsyd If you have a website that solely relies on the client time (ideally to give you some rewards), I'd like to...um... visit it.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed - the answer is quite simple and straightforward.

Comment: @shomz I didn't say to solely rely on client time, I said the actual countdown timer would need to be client side. Validation would still need to be server based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store the time on the server, it could be either the time something started (and you need to know the duration) or the time it ends.

On the client-side, you read this value and make a timer that will tick inside the browser, based on the time you fetched from the server.

Here's a super-simple example that will use browser's `localStorage` to store the time value. It will show the time passed since you first opened the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ceyw1v5a/

Try refreshing the link to see how the timer value is persistent. I wanted to do it here as a snippet, but it's doesn't allow localStorage for security reasons.

---

Anyway, because the client-side timer can be easily tampered with, you should **never, ever** rely on it! That means, say you have a game, and when a certain time expires, you get a gold coin, you should **always** check for the time expiry *on the server* because malicious users can easily set the timer to zero and make the server call, but it's up to that server to figure out whether the time had really expired or there's a cheat attempt.

---

UPDATE

> when you build up a building or do start a research, a countdown starts for that building etc..

In that case, the process would go something like this:

- user clicks the build button
- a server call is made to check if you're allowed to build it (check resources, etc...) and if so, it stores the timestamp when the construction of that particular building has started
- based on the construction duration, the timer appears on the client side (the browser), counting down
- if the user reconnects, the "currently building" values for all the buildings are read from the server side storage, and the client side timer is relaunched based on the remaining duration
- when the timer expires on the client side, a server call is made (as described above), and if the timer on the server side has expired as well (meaning the building is complete), you remove the timer on the client side and show the completed building
- if the user leaves before the building is complete and reconnects after it's complete, you simply show the completed building on the client side, no timers needed

About the actual process of getting the data from the server will vary, depending on your app structure. For example, you can make AJAX call(s) to fetch the server data when the game runs, etc.

Comment: This is a good answer for me. Thank you for your help. I wish I could vote up all your answers but I am below 15 reputation.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry about your reputation, just keep asking good questions and you'll get it in no time.

Comment: About the answer, I hope you understood the relationship between localStorage (which is the only thing I could use here without making a server) and the data you'd get externally using PHP.

Comment: I guess, I understood. Right now, I am making a website to do some practice about it. If I have any question, I will ask in this page again.

Comment: Alright, I'll update my answer to address it more specifically in a minute.

Comment: Shornz thank you very much brother! Thank you for taking time to explain all this to me! With all the answers here, everything make more sense now.

Comment: I have just completed my countdown application! Thank you again. As you said, I need to store start time of the event and also I need store duration time or the end time. Because endTime - startTime gives me durationTime, and startTime + durationTime gives me endTime. So choosing one of them to store into database is the most efficient way.

Comment: Exactly, great job! You're welcome again. Why don't you accept an answer that helped you the most so this question is no longer active?

Answer (score 2):

Use php to get the current time and calculate the end time of the event.

```
<?php
$event_action_time = "3600"; // 1 hour in seconds
$time = time(); // current time
$endtime = $time + $event_action_time; // future date for event to end
// Store endtime in DB
?>
```

Now that you have the end time you can query the db for any events that have not ended based on the current time. If there are results you can then assign the end time result to a variable in php and pass it to preferably a [jquery countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

Comment: Thank you Brian. I'll do some practice to make it perfectly clear for myself.